# Which iPad suffix do I use?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

Do I use Icon-72.png and Icon-72@2x.png or do I use Icon~ipad.png and Icon~ipad@2x.png I am hearing different answers and I am confused. What iPad icons suffix do I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) is a link describing all the names for each of the icons, and what they are used for. I use `Icon-72.png` and `Icon-72@2x.png` in my projects, and it works perfectly!

Hope that helps!

Comment: It might be, but I wouldn't use it when you know that the first 2 options work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I use the first two. It gets the regular and retina (@2x). Although you can specify whatever you want in the Build Settings.